# RecyclerView gesture listener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple layout with a `RecyclerView` and custom `ViewGroup`  above recycler with a `SimpleOnGestureListener` on my `ViewGroup`.
`SimpleOnGestureListener` i need to detect swipe left/swipe right events in `onFling` callback.

Swipe detection work fine, but recycler item are not clickable for now.
I have tried to handle `onSingleTapUp()` event in `SimpleOnGestureListener` and process it to recycler by `recyclerView.onTouchEvent(e)` but it's not not working.

Also tried to manage `onTouchEvent` like below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    LayoutManager manager = getLayoutManager();
    if (manager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < manager.getItemCount(); i++) {
            manager.getChildAt(i).onTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but click works only for 1'st recycler item.
Is there any way to handle swipe event with my `ViewGroup` which is above recycler and process click event to recyclerview items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In custom `RecyclerView` class override `onTouchEvent()`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
       // find if RecyclerView item exists with given coordinates
        View childView = findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        //if exists - perform click
        if (childView != null) {
            childView.performClick();
        }
        return false;
    }
```